# Segmentation Fault when using Bitwise Operators

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, decimal

I'm currently messing around with a project in C that will take in two 8-bit binary numbers and convert them to decimal values. I have a good understanding of the bit-wise operators in C and how they treat numbers, my question is one that revolves around syntax.

ATM my program is very simple:

```
int main() {
  char *inp1;
  char *inp2;
  unsigned long binNum1;
  unsigned long binNum2;

  printf("Enter the first binary number: "); 
  scanf("%s", inp1); 
  printf("Enter the second binary number: "); 
  scanf("%s", inp2); 

  binNum1 = strtoul(inp1, NULL, 2);
  binNum2 = strtoul(inp1, NULL, 2);

  unsigned long orVal = binNum1 | binNum2;
  unsigned long andVal = binNum1 & binNum2;
  unsigned long exclVal = binNum1 ^ binNum2;

  printf("Your or value is: %lu", orVal);
  printf("Your and value is: %lu", andVal);
  printf("Your exclusive value is: %lu", exclVal);

  return 0;
}
```

Essentially, I just want to get the value of ORing, ANDing, and EXCLing the two decimal values of each binary number. However, I get a segmentation fault when I run this. I'm pretty sure this is due to syntax, but I can't find much online for this type of problem.

Comment: In other words, what valid memory do `inp1` and `inp2` point to before you attempt to use them? Perhaps `char inp1[65]`; (64+1 bytes of storage)?

Comment: `binNum2 = strtoul(inp1, NULL, 2);`, presumably you'd want this to actually be `binNum2 = strtoul(inp2, NULL, 2);` ..?

Comment: @David C. Rankin You and another individual who answered about allocating memory are correct. I also appreciate your answers on some of my previous posts yesterday!

Comment: Glad it helps. We will turn you into a programmer yet. Go revisit my answer and look at the validations. They may seem like unnecessary work for short examples, but building good habits early avoids *Undefined Behavior* later.... Understanding how to validate every critical step in your code is the foundation of programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With these lines

```
char *inp1;
char *inp2;
...
scanf("%s", inp1);
scanf("%s", inp2);
```

you have not assigned any memory to `inp1` or to `inp2`. The pointers are *uninitialised* and this is the probable cause of the segfault.

To simplify it you could do it like this:

```
char inp1[100];
printf("Enter the first binary number: "); 
if(scanf("%99s", inp1) != 1) {
    return 1;
}
```

and similarly for `inp2`.

Comment: You were right! After declaring memory manually, it worked jsut fine:     char *bitStr = (char *)malloc(9*sizeof(char));

Comment: That will only allow you to enter 8 bits, but you are dealing with `unsigned long` values which are typically 32 bits these days. It's always worth restricting the input length for `scanf` as in my example.